# Service starts when I open the activity without reason

Tags: java, android, android-service

I'm using this code:

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private ServiceSpeechRecognition service;
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
            ServiceSpeechRecognition.MyBinder b = (ServiceSpeechRecognition.MyBinder) binder;
            service = b.getService();

            Log.e(TAG, "Service connected");
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            savePrefs();

            service = null;

            Log.e(TAG, "Service disconnected");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ui_main);

        getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, getPackageName() + ".MainActivity-Alias"), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        GoogleSearchApi.registerQueryGroup(this, ReceiverGoogleSearch.group);

        // Load prefs
        SharedPreferences prefs = ActivityMain.getPrefs(this);
        String key_phrase = prefs.getString(Preferences.KEY_PHRASE_KEY, Preferences.DEFAULT_KEY_PHRASE);
        boolean require_charge = prefs.getBoolean(Preferences.KEY_REQUIRE_CHARGER, true);

        // Update Ui
        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.key_phrase);
        text.setText(key_phrase);

        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.require_battery);
        checkbox.setChecked(require_charge);

        // If should, start intent
        if (!require_charge || Util.isCharging(this)) {
            bindIntent();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {        
        if (service != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unbind");

            unbindService(mConnection);
        }

        super.onPause();
    }

    private void bindIntent() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bind intent");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceSpeechRecognition.class);
        startService(intent);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, 0);
    }

    public void setKeyPhrase(View view) {
        savePrefs();

        if (service != null) {
            EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.key_phrase);
            String key_phrase = text.getText().toString();

            service.setKeyPhrase(key_phrase);
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.str_key_phrase_updated, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void setRequireCharge(View view) {
        savePrefs();

        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) view;
        boolean require_charge = checkbox.isChecked();

        if (service != null) {
            service.setRequiresCharge(require_charge);
        } else if (!require_charge || Util.isCharging(this)) {
            bindIntent();
        }
    }

    public void savePrefs() {
        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.key_phrase);
        String key_phrase = text.getText().toString();

        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.require_battery);
        boolean require_charge = checkbox.isChecked();

        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = ActivityMain.getPrefs(this).edit();

        prefs.putString(Preferences.KEY_PHRASE_KEY, key_phrase);
        prefs.putBoolean(Preferences.KEY_REQUIRE_CHARGER, require_charge);

        prefs.commit();
    }

    public static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(Preferences.KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE | Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);   
    }
}
```

this is an activity in which starts a service.. The problem is that the service starts as soon as the activity it opens. I would create a button or checkbox to start it. But now when I open the activity it starts the service. I didn't write any `startService()` in the onCreate() method.

Comment: Could you please change the title to something that makes a little more sense than _Service starts when i wont_?

Comment: I think your bindIntent function is invoking in onResume, please confirm it first

Comment: The method `bindIntent()` gets called in `onResume()` and this is what starts your `Service`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You Start Your Service in On Resume so Replace

```
private void bindIntent() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bind intent");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceSpeechRecognition.class);
        startService(intent);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, 0);
    }
```

to

```
private void bindIntent() {
            Log.e(TAG, "Bind intent");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceSpeechRecognition.class);
            bindService(intent, mConnection, 0);
        }
```

Put below code in your button click event.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceSpeechRecognition.class);
startService(intent);
```

Thats it....

Comment: Thank you. But in this way if i click in the checkbox it starts service but not stops.

Comment: Create method StopService in Service class and call it when you want to stop service.thats it.